# How to replace a string with regular expression looking for ':' and variable white space?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

Say I have a string:

> public class MyClass : BaseClass

I want to replace "MyClass" with an arbitrary replacement like "MyNewClass"

I can do this with a regular expression like this:

```
Regex.Replace(fileOrigContents, $@"([^\p{{L}}0-9\.]){oldClassName}([^\p{{L}}0-9:])", $"$1{newClassName}$2$3");
```

However that doesn't cover the cases where the string could be

> public class MyClass: BaseClass

or

> public class MyClass:BaseClass

In these cases, the string replacement doesn't occur.

For the second case, I was able to get it to work via this modification:

```
Regex.Replace(fileOrigContents, $@"([^\p{{L}}0-9\.]){oldClassName}(\s*:\s*[^\p{{L}}0-9:])", $"$1{newClassName}$2");
```

But that doesn't work for the third case. How can I replace the class name and cover any combination of whitespace and ':' using a regular expression?

Comment: I would expect your "modification" to work for any combination of whitespace before and after the semicolon. So it's not clear what your problem is. You need to provide a good [mcve] that shows exactly what you mean by _"that doesn't work"_.

Comment: Just to make it clear: your regex has two capturing groups, but your replacement pattern has three plecholders, `$1`, `$2` and `$3` - why? Or is the pattern you posted is not the one you are actually using?

Comment: Also, the two cases you mention do not work because your last capturing group pattern matches any char but letter, digit and a colon. If you remove it, they will get matched, see [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5b%5e%5cp%7bL%7d0-9.%5d%29MyClass%28%5b%5e%5cp%7bL%7d0-9%5d%29&i=public+class+MyClass+%3a+BaseClass%0d%0apublic+class+MyClass%3a+BaseClass%0d%0apublic+class+MyClass%3aBaseClass&r=).

Answer (score 0):

See if this works: `(?<=public class )MyClass *(?=:)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oX50Ni/1)